# resource(4) of type (mysql link) Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate the percentage of `progressDone` by adding all `progressDone` and dividing it with the numbers of progress done. it is not working and i am also getting error

> resource(4) of type (mysql link)
>   Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(progressDone) AS totall, COUNT(progressDone) AS done FROM  progress, progressType WHERE progress.projectID='$projectID' AND progress.progressTypeID='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db)
or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error()." Actual query: ".$query);
$online = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$total = done; //done from the sql statement 
$current = $online;
$percent = (($current/$total) * 100);
$percentNot = 100 - $percent;
```

Comment: You are calling `mysql_fetch_object`. Why would you think you could use `$online` as an integer? It is an _object_

Comment: You need to [stop using mysql_ functions, as they are no longer in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
$online = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$total = done; //done from the sql statement 
$current = $online;
```

`mysql_fetch_object` returns an object. You can't just reference the columns like this. You need to call the columns as members of the object

```
$total = $online->done;
$current = $online->totall;
```